# not able to execute lsnrctr status command using java code

Tags: ssh

I am connecting remote server using java code, but one of the unix command is not executing as expected.
Unix Command as below :

```
 /u01/db/oracle/db/tech_st/11.1.0/bin/lsnrctl status VIS
```

Output:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on 06-NOV-2017 10:48:10

Copyright (c) 1991, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01101: Message 1101 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
```

can any one help me to on this.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to test it from the command line first. The point is you run `lsnrctl` without required environment variable `ORACLE_HOME`.

Here you have it reproduced:

```
jxa@ub16a|2001$ ssh test1 /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl status
Message 1053 not found; No message file for product=network,
facility=TNSMessage 1020 not found; No message file for product=network,
facility=TNSMessage 1021 not found; No message file for product=network,
facility=TNSMessage 1022 not found;
[...]
```

After setting correctly `ORACLE_HOME` (add it before the command):

```
jxa@ub16a|2007$ ssh test1 ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 \
                     /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 09-NOV-2017 12:35:56
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
[...]
```

Now just figure out the way to add the environment variable in java and you're done. Or just add it to `.bashrc` (the most probable place for Linux) or another appropriate init file at the target host.

By the way, the error your `lsnrctl` reports is:

```
xxx:~ $ oerr tns 1101
01101, 00000, "Could not find service name %s"
// *Cause:  The ervice name could not be resolved by name-lookup.
// *Action: Verify that the listener name or service name specified to
// LSNRCTL has the correct name and address defined in LISTENER.ORA or in
// TNSNAMES.ORA.
xxx:~ $
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your update. before executing the command itself we set the ORACLE_HOME , the command perfectly executing in Linux server , but what we facing issue that when we execute the command through java code we are not able to get the out put.

Comment: Quote the problem code here - I cannot figure out why you cannot get the output.

Comment: String instancesResponse = client.runCommand((String)/u01/db/oracle/db/tech_st/11.1.0/bin/lsnrctl status VIS + "  | grep Service ");      i am using jssh.jar file

Comment: Does it work where you call it from another system with ssh? Eg ssh targetsystem /u01/db/oracle/db/tech_st/11.1.0/b‌​in/lsnrctl status VIS.

Comment: No i am not getting output, but getting as "LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on 06-NOV-2017 10:48:10

Copyright (c) 1991, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01101: Message 1101 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS"

Comment: OK then please add ORACLE_HOME before the binary name, now it would be ssh targetsystem ORACLE_HOME=/u01/db/oracle/db/tech_st/11.1.0 u01/db/oracle/db/tech_st/11.1.0/b‌​in/lsnrctl status VIS. I guessed the ORACLE_HOME value from your input. Please adjust accordingly.

Comment: i have export ORACLE_HOME dynamically, after that i am trying to execute the " /u01/db/oracle/db/tech_st/11.1.0/bin/lsnrctl status VIS", but not able to get the output using java code, but if i ran same command directly in Linux i am able to get the output.